# Missing credential for passport registering/login

Tags: node.js, passport.js, passport-local

I'm having a nodejs app, using passport for authentication.

Currently, I'm having a problem with my register/login (I will just show the problem with register since those two have the same problem). When I tried to send a POST with 'email', 'password', 'fullname', it is logged in the console that

```
info { message: 'Missing credentials' }
```

The code that triggers this message is in auth.js below.

Could anyone please suggest a way to solve this?
Also, a side question, how can I get the id of the current user in the session? Should it be req.user or req.session.passport.user

Here is my app structure

```
├── config
│   ├── config.json
│   └── passport.js
├── models
│   ├── index.js
│   └── user.js
├── query.js
├── routes
│   ├── auth.js
└── server.js
```

**server.js**

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const cors = require('cors');
const passport     = require('passport');
const flash        = require('connect-flash');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const session      = require('express-session');

const app = express();
const port = process.env.port || 8080;

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded( {extended: false} ));
app.use(bodyParser.json());// pass the body as json

app.use(session({
  secret: 'goN6DJJC6E287cC77kkdYuNuAyWnz7Q3iZj8',
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: false,
  cookie: {
    expires: 600000
  }
}));

// PASSPORT: for passport authentication
require('./config/passport')(passport);
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session()); // persistent login sessions

// FLASH: for error messages
app.use(flash());

// ROUTES:
require('./routes/auth')(app, passport);
app.listen(port, () => { 
  console.log(`Server is running on port ${port}`) 
});
```

**passport.js** (beatiful source code from https://github.com/b0bbybaldi/Rent-All/blob/master/config/passport.js). Thanks b0bbybaldi :)))))

```
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;

var db  = require('../models');


module.exports = function(passport) {
    

    // SERIALIZE
    passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
        done(null, user.id);
    });

    // deserialize
    passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
        db.User.findById(id).then(function(user) {
            if (user) {
                done(null, user.get());
            } else {
                done(user.errors, null);
            }
        });
    });

    passport.use('local-signup', new LocalStrategy(
        {
            // by default, local strategy uses username and password, we will override with email
            usernameField: 'email',
            passwordField : 'password',
            passReqToCallback : true // allows us to pass back the entire request to the callback
        },
        function(req, email, password, done) {
            process.nextTick(function() {
                db.User.findOne({
                    where: {
                        email: req.body.email
                    }
                }).then(function(user, err){
                    if(err) {
                        console.log("err",err)
                        return done(err);
                    }
                    // check to see if theres already a user with that email
                    if (user) {
                        console.log('signupMessage', 'That email is already taken.');
                        return done(null, false, req.flash('signupMessage', 'That email is already taken.'));
                    } else {
                        // console.log("creating");

                        db.User.create({
                            email: req.body.email,
                            fullname:req.body.fullname,
                            password: db.User.generateHash(req.body.password)

                        }).then(function(dbUser) {
                            //console.log("created result: ", dbUser);
                            // send post back to render
                            console.log("User Created")
                            return done(null, dbUser);

                        }).catch(function (err) {
                            // handle error;
                            console.log(err);
                        });
                    }
                });
            });

        }));
}
```

**auth.js**

```
var db = require("../models");

module.exports = function (app, passport) {
    app.post('/signup', function(req, res, next) {
        passport.authenticate('local-signup', function(err, user, info) {
            console.log("info", info);
            if (err) {
                console.log("passport err", err);
                return next(err); // will generate a 500 error
            }
            // Generate a JSON response reflecting authentication status
            if (! user) {
                console.log("user error", user);
                return res.send({ success : false, message : 'authentication failed' });
            }

            req.login(user, loginErr => {
                if (loginErr) {
                    console.log("loginerr", loginErr)
                    return next(loginErr);
                }
                //var userId = user.dataValues.id;
                console.log('redirecting....');

                res.cookie('user_id', user.id);
                res.cookie('user_name', user.fullname );
                //return res.json("/accounts/view");
                console.log("Registered")
            });
        })(req, res, next);
    });

}
```

Comment: I'm not a js or node guru or expert, but don't you need the file extensions in your require statements? or is this still loading the resources ok? just asking as curious...

Comment: also why does db.User.findOne use Capitol but everywhere else it's lowercase?

Comment: @RyanStone Hi Ryan, about the file extensions, could you please elaborate more? I think the code between files can communicate properly. For the db.User.findOne and "user", let's think like this: in my folder models, which I imported as db in this case, there was a exported module called User; I used findOne as the method of this module. The "user", wrapped in then function, was just a variable that fetched the result from the findOne function. Does that make sense to you?

Comment: Sure... I know that when you require Built in Node Modules that they do not need an extention or an absolute path, But in your part where it say's "var db = require("../models")"  Not sure whether this was purposefully supposed to be Models or Modules but if it is a file you have created I think it needs the full path ie `models.js, models.php, models.html, models.jsx` etc.... If its not throwing an error then this might not be an issue, was just looking through your code trying to understand it better..

Comment: Hi Ryan, sorry for my late reply. "models" is a folder in this case, containing the modules inside. However, even if it is modules, I can still refer to it without the .js tail